# NSLog an array of CGPoints

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have declared the following CGPoint :

```
CGPoint borderVertices[5000];
```

I have added all the values to the array if I may call it (or just a set), but now I was wondering if there is anyway I can NSLog these points or copy them to a file.

I have tried :

```
NSLog(@"vertices %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(borderVertices));
```

but I get an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about:

```
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
{
   NSLog(@"vertices :%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(borderVertices[i]));
}
```

Comment: is there anyway I can dump the values all together in a file and read them from the file without doing it one by one?

Comment: Yes OR you could also make one big NSString from it and NSLog that. You should check [stringByAppendingString:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAppendingString:)

Answer (score 1):

Arrays like in plain old c, needs to be iterated to print each value at it's index.

```
NSLog(@"vertices %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(borderVertices));
```

The above statement would have worked if `borderVertices` is of type `CGPoint`. But it is not, it is of type `CGPoint[]`.

Answer (score 1):

You could make an array like:

```
CGPoint borderVertices[5000];
float bVx[5000];
float bVy[5000];
```

And assign values to `bVx` and `bVy` with `borderVertices.position.(x or y)` in a loop and then whenever you need the coordinates... there you have it.

Comment: NSLog("the x value is %f the y value is %f", bVx[number], bVy[number]);